# Splitting a list of lists and strings by a string

Tags: python, list, split

Is there a convenient pythonic way to split a list by a search string (even if the list contains non-strings and have nested lists).  For example, say I would like to split the following by ',':

```
[[ 'something', ',', 'eh' ], ',', ['more'], ',', 'yet more', '|', 'even more' ]
```

This would become:

```
[[[ 'something', ',', 'eh' ]], [['more']], ['yet more', '|', 'even more']]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: lst = [[ 'something', ',', 'eh' ], ',', ['more'], ',', 'yet more', '|', 'even more' ]

In [3]: [list(group) for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x!=',') if key]
Out[3]: [[['something', ',', 'eh']], [['more']], ['yet more', '|', 'even more']]
```

It basically splits items in your list into groups based on a criteria (`item != ','`) and the comprehension check `if k` filters out the groups that are `False`  –  that is the items that are equal to `','`.

```
In [4]: for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x!=','):
   ...:     print key, list(group)
   ...:     
True [['something', ',', 'eh']]
False [',']
True [['more']]
False [',']
True ['yet more', '|', 'even more']
```

Comment: @astex - well, it splits items in your list into groups based on `!=','` and the comprehension check `if k` filters out the groups that are `False` - that is the items that are equal to `','`.

Comment: Equivalently `from functools import partial` `from operator import ne` `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, key=partial(ne, ',')) if k]`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but FWIW, I think a combination of `itertools.takewhile` and `iter` with a sentinel value provides a quick solution

```
from itertools import takewhile

z = [[ 'something', ',', 'eh' ], ',', ['more'], ',',
  'yet more', '|', 'even more' ]
z = iter(z)
def provider():
  return list(takewhile(lambda x: x != ',', z))

for i in iter(provider, []):
  print i

... 
[['something', ',', 'eh']]
[['more']]
['yet more', '|', 'even more']
```